# How to remove AND delete folder from project in NuGet PowerShell install?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to remove and delete the files from a project during the install PowerShell of a NuGet package. I have the code below that removes it from the project, but I cannot figure out how to pipe that so I can also delete it from disk. How do I do this?

```
$project.ProjectItems.Item("Test123").Remove() | Select-Object | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item -force -recurse
```

Comment: What does the `Remove` method return?

Comment: Hmmm not sure how to debug PowerShell especially if NuGet is triggering it (I'm a newbie to ps)

Comment: Looks like it's [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.remove.aspx), returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like instead of calling [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.remove.aspx) you should call [`Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.delete.aspx).

From documentation for `Remove`

> Removes the project item from the collection.

From documentation for `Delete` *emphasis mine*

> Removes the item from its project **and its storage**.

Comment: @TruMan1: MSDN is your friend, don't be shy about digging around the documentation.